# continuous function f maps closed set to closed set

Tags: real-analysis

I know it's false.I am unable to find logical flaw in the following proof:

$S⊂R$ is a closed set and $F:S→R$ is continuous on $S$.

seq $x_n→x$ implies $F(x_n)→F(x)$. (by continuity of $F$)

Since $x$ belongs to $S$ ($S$ is closed), $F(x)$ belongs to $F(S)$.

This implies $F(S)$ is a closed set.

Comment: The range of $\mathrm{arctan}(x)$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ Do you see the flaw now?

Comment: Or even better, function $\max\{-x,\arctan x\}$, that maps $S=[0,\infty)$ to $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)$. In this case, $\frac\pi2$ is a limit point of $F(S)$, it is in the image of $f$, but there is no convergent sequence in $S$ mapping to a sequence which converges to $\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't show that the set $F(S)$ is closed. To show that $F(S)$ is closed, you need to show that whenever $y\in\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $F(S)$, then $y$ belongs to $F(S)$. You are implicitly assuming that every limit point of $F(S)$ is already of the form $f(x)$ for some $x\in S$, which need not be the case as RideTheWavelet pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The argument should be like: let $y_n \to z$, $y_n = F(x_n)$. Then somehow you are trying to prove that $z \in F(S)$. The only problem is that $x_n$ itself might not be convergent, in fact, it might not have any convergent subsequences. So you cannot get $x_n \to x$ from anywhere.

A basic example is $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. The image of the closed set $[0, \infty)$ is $(0,1]$.

Note however that in general, if $S$ is closed and bounded then the image of $S$ will be closed ( and bounded).